# In AppCode, is there a way of filtering the list of classes presented on the 'navigate to class' dropdown (⌘N)?

Tags: objective-c, appcode

I'm building an iOS application, and have a need for making a large number of duplicated classes with the same name (actual implementation, vs. sample data implementation).

Let's say I have some class `Foobar` in my app; there'll be at least two different implementations of the same (i.e. one `Foobar.h` file and two `Foobar.m`). Trust me. I'm not crazy, and I have a use for this.

When I type ⌘N to navigate to the class (or the file, for that matter) it would look something like this:

[image: Screenie]

... but with a lot of duplicate entries. Is there any way to tell AppCode to only display suggestions from a particular subtree of the files in my project, or show only suggestions relevant to the target currently selected?